# Is this an optimal implementation for the knapsack algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, hash-map, knapsack-problem

I have implemented a solution for the **knapsack problem** while breaking an item is allowed. I've used the dictionary data structure where I used weight as a key and value per weight as a value. After that, I sorted the dictionary by value and filled the knapsack until there's no space left.

Here is my python code -

```
def calculateKnapsack():
    userinputNW = list(map(int, input().split()))
    n = userinputNW[0]
    weight = userinputNW[1]
    weightvaluedict = {}
    revenue = 0
    for x in range(n):
        vw = list(map(int, input().split()))
        weightvaluedict[vw[1]] = vw[0]/vw[1]
    weightvaluedict = {k: v for k, v in sorted(
        weightvaluedict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}
    for k, v in weightvaluedict.items():
        if weight == 0:
            break
        if k < weight:
            revenue += k * v
            weight -= k
        else:
            revenue += weight * v
            weight = 0
    return revenue
```

I'm confused if it is an optimal solution or not. I searched online and most of the tutorial used 2D array. I wanted to ensure my code's optimality. Suggestions are welcome.

Thanks. And also this is my first question on the Code review platform so please forgive me if I did anything wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you mean by "the knapsack problem white fraction is allowed," not even if I assume that the word "white" should have been "while" or "what" or "where". The whole thing that makes the knapsack problem NP-hard is that you're *not* allowed to break up a single item into "fractions." So to understand what you meant, I tried to look at the code.

The first thing I do to understand a piece of code is, I look at its function signature. What arguments does the function take? What verbs and prepositions are used in its name? Consider:

```
def countPrimesUpTo(n):
def listPrimesUpTo(n):
def printPrimesLessThan(n):
```

Here's your function signature.

```
def calculateKnapsack():
```

Well, that didn't give me any information at all...!

The second way I try to understand a piece of code is to look at what it does; that is, look at its unit-tests.

```
assert listPrimesUpTo(10) == [2,3,5,7]
assert listPrimesUpTo(5) == [5]
assert listPrimesUpTo(1) == []
```

Here's your unit tests.

```
pass
```

Okay, I guess I should just give up on understanding what the code is intended to do, and focus on the code itself.

```
    userinputNW = list(map(int, input().split()))
    n = userinputNW[0]
    weight = userinputNW[1]
```

Oh hey! Here's something that looks like function arguments. You could immediately refactor your function into

```
def computeKnapsack(n, weight):
```

But then I go on and I see there's more input happening later...

```
    weightvaluedict = {}
    for x in range(n):
        vw = list(map(int, input().split()))
        weightvaluedict[vw[1]] = vw[0]/vw[1]
    weightvaluedict = {k: v for k, v in sorted(
        weightvaluedict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}
```

So now our knapsack function looks like

```
def computeKnapsackRevenue(weights, capacity):
    revenue = 0
    for size, value in weights.items():
        if capacity == 0:
            break
        if size < capacity:
            revenue += size * value
            capacity -= size
        else:
            revenue += capacity * value
            capacity = 0
    return revenue
```

and we have some boilerplate user-input code that looks like

```
    num_items, capacity = map(int, input().split())
    weights = {}
    for x in range(num_items):
        v, k = map(int, input().split())
        weights[k] = v / k
    weights = {k: v for k, v in sorted(
        weights.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)}
```

That last line isn't doing anything at all. It doesn't matter *how* you permute the list of items, if all you're doing with the result is stuffing it back into an unsorted `dict`. So we can erase that line.

```
    num_items, capacity = map(int, input().split())
    weights = {}
    for x in range(num_items):
        v, k = map(int, input().split())
        weights[k] = v / k
    revenue = computeKnapsackRevenue(weights, capacity)
    print(revenue)
```

And there's our program! We might add some unit tests to prove that it does what we expect:

```
    assert computeKnapsackRevenue({10: 8, 10: 9, 10: 10}, 0) == 0
    assert computeKnapsackRevenue({10: 8, 10: 9, 10: 10}, 20) == 190
    assert computeKnapsackRevenue({10: 8, 10: 9, 10: 10}, 25) == 230
    assert computeKnapsackRevenue({10: 8, 10: 9, 10: 10}, 30) == 270
    assert computeKnapsackRevenue({10: 8, 10: 9, 10: 10}, 40) == 270
    assert computeKnapsackRevenue({}, 40) == 0
```

We might even find that it has a bug. :)

Comment: The problem is exactly written like this - "A thief finds much more loot than his bag can fit. Help him to find the most valuable combination of items assuming that any fraction of a loot item can be put into his bag." I misspelled the word while.

Comment: I tasted again and already found a bug , I'm working on it

Comment: @MahmudulHasan: For future reference, it would have been a good idea to put that problem statement ("A thief finds...") at the top of your question.